# Does Azure Blob filter "prefix" of blob's name?

Tags: c#, performance, azure, blob, azure-storage

The requirement is get all available BlockBlob that's name start with given prefix:
I used API:

```
 CloudBlobClient.ListBlobs(prefix: "test").OfType<CloudBlockBlob>.Select(b=> b.Name).ToList();
```

I wonder how this API work:

1. Client load all blob's metadata , then filter the blob's name
2. Server do the filter, then return the blob's name.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to worry, the Server will do the filter.

Comment: Thank you for answer. 
There is a one concern. Select(b=>b.Name). This code will be executed after client get CloudBlockBlob objects or server will return to user list of name?

Comment: Yes, the Select statement will be executed after the client retrieved the list of IListBlobItem